# user defined commands in verbatim environment

Tags: latex, verbatim

is it possible to create a new command with a parameter in a verbatim environment and some indentation?

```
\newcommand{codeblock}[1]{\begin{quote}\begin{verbatim}#1\end{verbatim}\end{quote}}
```

This does not work. Is there an other way?

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.  There are many [questions there related to the listings package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings) which might be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to have code in your document, in which case you're probably better served by the package listings than by verbatim. Listings also gives you nice features like line numbering and syntax highlighting for many common languages. See http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/ if it's not already installed with your LaTeX distribution.

Answer (score 5):

How `\begin{verbatim}` works. briefly and roughly.

1. `\begin{verbatim}` is expanded to `\verbatim`.
2. Then `\verbatim` sets category code of each special characters to 12. 
   Now all chars is like digits or puncts.
3. Then `\verbatim` sets font, parindent and calls `\@xverbatim`.
4. `\@xverbatim` catches the end of verbatim using the following trick:

   ```
   \def\@xverbatim#1\end{#1\end}
   ```
5. Then `\end{verbatim}` finishes work.

How `\newcommand{\codeblock}[1]{\begin{quote}\begin{verbatim}#1\end{verbatim}\end{quote}}` works.

1. First of all `\codeblock{Some {}$&%^_}` reads its argument.
2. `#1 --> Some code {}$&%^_`

   **Note:** `{`,`}`,`$`,`&`,`%`,`^`,`_` have categories 1,2,3,4,6,7,8 **rather than 11 or 12!!!**)
3. `\codeblock` expands to `\begin{quote}\begin{verbatim} Some {}$&%^_\end {verbatim}\end {quote}`.
    **Important:** backslash of `\end` has category 0 rather than 11. 
    Moreover `{` and `}` have categories 1 and 2  rather than 11. 
    And `$`,`&`,`%`,`^`,`_` have categories 3,4,6,7,8.
4. `\begin{quote}` expands to `\quote` and `\quote` executes.
5. Then `\begin{verbatim}` expands to `\varbatim`. 
    `\varbatim` changes all categories and font. But (**important**)
    the category of backslash (in `\end`) remains equal to 0. And the categories of `{`, `}`, `$`, `&`, `%`, `^`, `_` typed after `Some` remains because of "argument reading" executes before `\verbatim` changes all categories. But you need that all char has categories 11 o 12.
6. Then `\verbatim` calls `\@xverbatim`.
7. `\@xverbatim` tries to catch your argument using the following trick:

   ```
   \def\@xverbatim#1\end{#1\end}
   ```

   but it is impossible because of `\@xverbatim` tries to catch
     `\end` where all letters (`\`,`e`,`n`,`d`) have the category 12 and 11.
     But in fact there are four letters with other category code:
     `\` with category 0 and `e`,`n`,`d` with category 11.

   It is possible (I am not sure) that trick is more masterly:

   [image]

   Red chars have category 12. Green chars have category 11. 
    `\def`, `\@xverbatim`, `\end` are macros with `\` (category 0) and letters (category 11).
8. `\@xverbatim` is trying and trying to find `\end` where backslash (`\`) has category 11 but.... `File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim`

If you want to create new macro `\codeblock` you must do something like above text.